# What are the regulations for sports hunting (Trophies and Big Game)

Tags: halal-haram, sports, hunting

Is hunting permitted in Islam as a sport? If so What is the rules for hunting in Islam (Sport and Business)?

PS: I am a professional hunter. I hear that according to Quran whatever you spot in the bush that is halal can be taken as it is a blessing of God and therefore has to be harvested (Obviously this is a huge breech of the laws and it could get me into serious troubles and make me loose my job).

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/194080